# Regex negative lookbehind AND positive lookahead

Tags: c#, regex, elasticsearch

I'm trying to parse an `elasticsearch` query string and remove all invalid `*` characters using `negative lookbehind` and `negative lookahead`.

For example, the following are legitimate uses:

```
[10 to *]
{* TO 2012-01-01}
{     * TO 2012-01-01}
steakhou*
```

These are not legitimate:

```
10 to *  (no brackets)
[10 to * (no proceeding bracket)
*ab      (leading *)
*        (standalone)
```

The expression I've come up with works for the most part except I can't figure out how to also `lookahead` and check if there is no closing `},)` or `]`

```
(?<!(?i)TO\s|\w|\[|\[\s|\]|\{|\()\*
```

[image] as you can see the `*` near the beginning of the sample text isn't matched

**Edit:** link for regex tester that allows lookahead/lookbehind
https://regex101.com/

sample text:

```
[1 to 5] 2 TO * -sample *0-9AZc *testing * 2344 +field value some_field mmm e-A[0-9]* [ *p{L} [n-z]] broken*
awef * sdf TZ* [* i sto 5] {* to 3}
```

Comment: Share the ling to the Regex101 snippet instead of posting this capture

Comment: added the link + sample text

Comment: Thanks. You know you can save the snippet?

Comment: Try `s = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\[[^][]*]|{[^{}]*}|\b\*\B)|\*", "$1");`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  that almost works except it's matching the `*` after a the word `broken*`

Comment: The asterisk is matched and captured so as to restore it in the replacement result. I understand `broken*` must remain intact.

Comment: ah seems I don't understand regex's reference enough. Thanks for the help, it seems to work perfect. Was going to post that it wasn't working till I realized `$1` is not just a random character your added lol. Mind posting your answer so i can accept